# how to keep the url from displaying when using a href=javascript:blah()

Tags: javascript, html

Don't know if this is easy or not (as I'm not well versed in javascript and/or html), but I'm trying to keep the url (in this case it's a function) from showing whenever there's a mouseover.  I've done it in HTML, but haven't using javascript.. my simple code is below...

```
<a href="javascript:CloseAndOpen(1);">Click Here</a>
```

I don't want the a href to appear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean appear like in the bottom left of the user's browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use JavaScript in "href" values at all.

```
<a href=# onclick='CloseAndOpen(1)'>Click Here</a>
```

Comment: it's a first that I'm learning not to use Javascript in href as I've seen it done.  Is it considered bad practice to do so?  BTW, thanks for your help. I added onmouseover and mouseout and it works as expected!

Comment: @Vernon it's absolutely everywhere, but it's a practice that should have died out by 1999 :-)  When you're looking around at web-based instructional materials, don't trust anything more than a couple years old!  Things change really fast.

Answer (score 1):

A link is supposed to show where it goes. If you don't want to show the address, don't use a link, just a regular element with a click event:

```
<span onclick="CloseAndOpen(1);">Click here</span>
```

You can use CSS to style it so that it looks like a link if you like.

Comment: works but doesn't exactly look like an active link on the page.  Thanks

Comment: @Vernon: You can use CSS to make it look exactly like a link, except that it doesn't show the href of course.